# can RN pass Apple appstore review?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store

Many iOS developers received the following message recently. Does it has any impact on React Native?

> Your app, extension, and/or linked framework appears to contain code
>   designed explicitly with the capability to change your app’s behavior
>   or functionality after App Review approval, which is not in compliance
>   with section 3.3.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement
>   and App Store Review Guideline 2.5.2. This code, combined with a
>   remote resource, can facilitate significant changes to your app’s
>   behavior compared to when it was initially reviewed for the App Store.
>   While you may not be using this functionality currently, it has the
>   potential to load private frameworks, private methods, and enable
>   future feature changes. This includes any code which passes arbitrary
>   parameters to dynamic methods such as dlopen(), dlsym(),
>   respondsToSelector:, performSelector:,
>   method_exchangeImplementations(), and running remote scripts in order
>   to change app behavior or call SPI, based on the contents of the
>   downloaded script. Even if the remote resource is not intentionally
>   malicious, it could easily be hijacked via a Man In The Middle (MiTM)
>   attack, which can pose a serious security vulnerability to users of
>   your app. Please perform an in-depth review of your app and remove any
>   code, frameworks, or SDKs that fall in line with the functionality
>   described above before submitting the next update for your app for
>   review.

Comment: There is a discussion on github rn https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12778 with the result that it is NOT about RN if normal usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recent action by Apple seems to target frameworks that are about to modify native code bundles on the fly. If you are using this kind of library in your RN project then you might get effected. But if you are using a library like Code Push which lets you modify js bundle, you are not expected to get effected. There is a [HN thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13817557) about it. You can search for `Microsoft` keyword to read about. You can also read [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13818211).